# flex-wrap: nowrap with row and column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a flex container with nowrap flow, some items might start as column, how can I manage them? It's like a tree layout. 
Final result might be like this image:
 [image]

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2yrbse) and snippet:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
  border:2px solid gray;
}

.item{
  width: 150px;
  flex:1 1 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried already and what's your current code?

Comment: Add some code .

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2yrbse

Comment: here's snippet.

Comment: I really don't understand, what you are trying to achieve

Comment: i need layout, which example you can see in attached photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of CSS grid layout to make this layout easily:

- use `grid-auto-flow: column` so that the items are placed in the column direction,
- use `grid-row` and `grid-column` to the specific `item` elements to achieve the configuration required.

See demo below:

```css
.container{
  display: inline-grid; /* inline grid container */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* items placed vertically */
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 1;
}
.item:nth-child(4),
.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.item:last-child {
  grid-row: 4;
}

.item{
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what i meant, i've tried grid layout before, but i added wrong column row values. One more time thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using tables.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">1</td>
    <td class="item">2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="item">3</td>
    <td class="item">4</td>
    <td class="item">5</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="item">6</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="item">7</td>
    <td class="item">8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, it will works if i have static data, but now i'm workin' with the dynamic data